# Comparing dates in MySQL using PDO (PHP) not working using YYYY-mm-dd format

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, phpstorm

I am trying to get records from between two dates using MySQL and PDO PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM tripTable AS trip
WHERE trip.travelDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

This doesn't seem to work when using the ***$_POST*** date variables of **1970-01-01** and **2099-01-01** but works when I convert those to variables to **19700101** and **20990101** respectively.

`travelDate` is stored as date format.

`:startDate` being 1970-01-01 and `:endDate` being 2099-01-01

Example PHP Code

```
$startDate = $_POST["startdate"];
$endDate = $_POST["enddate"];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare(/*above query*/);
$stmt->bindValue(":startDate", $startDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(":endDate", $endDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Why is this and is there a way I can remedy this in my SQL query?

I am testing the query using PhpStorm 2019.3.4's built in Query Console

Comment: Date fields stored as .. char/text?!

Comment: What does the data in your table look like?

Comment: @Nick single table with ID (int 11), travelDate (date), returnDate (date). E.g. 1,2019-04-11,2019-04-16

Comment: @LiamPillay include your PHP code.

Comment: Your query should work fine. We would need to see your PHP code to understand the problem.

Comment: @Nick added the PHP code used but it works fine elsewhere. I am executing the SQL in intellij's phpstorm 2019.3.4 'Query Console'

Comment: The query looks fine and works as anticipated https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4Au62CSmuSXCoyEaNkEGJL/0. The PHP code looks fine too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround your value with quotes when executing a query with parameters.

[image]

The actual SQL that gets executed (you can see that in the "Output" tab your your DB query console, see 2nd screenshot):

```sql
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE created_at >= '2019-04-25'
```

If you omit them, then it will be executed like this, which is wrong:

```sql
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE created_at >= 2019-04-25
```

You may see how many results are fetched using all 3 ways (table has 13 rows, correct query should return only 11 rows):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue was but I tested it again outside the PHPStorm Query Console and it seems to work outside the console. It seems PHPStorm requires PDO type dates to be written as YYYYmmdd **ONLY**

Comment: I've been using PDO for years and never had to do this.

Comment: @Barmar are you using PHPStorm? I think the issue here is that the testing environment (PHPStorm's Query Console) doesn't seem to like any date style other than YYYYmmdd. So it's not an issue with PHP but rather just the test environment

Comment: I thought the error was happening in your PDO code.

Comment: I do use PHPStorm, but I don't use its built-in webserver for testing, I run the PHP code on a real server.

Comment: @Barmar It's sort of mixed between the PDO style of `:value` and the PHPStorm MySQL  query console. I should have worded the question better but I had no idea what was wrong when I originally wrote it, and I plan to keep it the same in case someone else runs into the issue.

Comment: When you did it in the query console, did you put the date inside quotes? `WHERE trip.travelDate BETWEEN '1970-01-01` and `2099-01-01'`?

Comment: If you don't quote it, it performs arithmetic. `1970-01-01 = 1968`. `-` is the subtraction operator.

Comment: @Barmar yeah the literal string insertion of '1970-01-01' and '2099-01-01' worked but when you go CTRL+ENTER in the console to run the statement with :startDate and :endDate and enter 1970-01-01 or 2099-01-01 it didn't work... and I just realised the CTRL+ENTER prompt probably needs to be in string format with quotation marks too.

Comment: You can't use `:startdate` in the console. It doesn't execute PDO, it executes SQL queries directly.

Comment: @Barmar IDE recognizes common placeholder patterns, and custom ones can be added in `Settings/(Preferences | Tools | Database | User Parameters`. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html. See https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/executing.html#user , User parameters section.

Comment: @LiamPillay Check the gif at "User parameters" section https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/executing.html#user -- you will see that for strings it needs quotes as well. The same IS required for dates as well (you can look at the "Output" tab of your DB query console to see the actual SQL code that was executed.

Comment: I didn't know about that. But it still requires you to enter the value the way you would put it in code. Notice in the GIF that when they enter a string value for `:b` they put it in quotes.

Comment: @Barmar Correct. I believe it's because they do not run actuall Prepared Statements but do a simple text substitution in order to show the actual/final SQL in the Output panel.